# Making drop down menu for every grid item on page instead of just navbar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-grid

I am using CSS grid to layout my web page, I searched tutorials but all of them just tell how to make a dropdown for the navbar. Also, my web page is using CSS grid.

The following code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}

:root {
  --blue: lightgrey;
  --white: black;
  --border: #edc967;
  --holder: #ccb8b8;
  --active: #b2a3a3;
}

::selection {
  background-color: var(--border);
  color: var(--white);
}

body {
  color: var(--white);
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: var(--blue);
  grid-column: 1/7;
  padding: 17px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid var(--border);
}

.header h1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

/* Dashobaord Css */

.box {
  background-color: var(--blue);
  width: 80%;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 2px dashed var(--border);
  height: 70%;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: end;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: var(--white);
}

.box:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 3px solid var(--border);
}

.box:active {
  background-color: var(--active);
}

.title {
  grid-column: 1/7;
  width: 455.75px;
}

/* Dashobaord Css End */
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ht.css">
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="header">
            <h1>Company</h1>
          </div>
          <a class="box inv" href="#">
            <div>Inventory</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box transact" href="#">
            <div>Issue / Receive</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box ledger" href="#">
            <div>Ledgers</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box customer" href="#">
            <div>Customers</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box treasury" href="#">
            <div>Expenses</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box treasury" href="#">
            <div>Expense Transaction</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box treasury" href="#">
            <div>Profit</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Example: when I click or hover on the `.transact` anchor tag, I want it to display a dropdown with values of 'Customer', 'Worker' and 'Contract worker'

I am new to CSS and will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dropdown content:

```html
<a class="box transact" href="#">
  <div>Issue / Receive</div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <p>Customer</p>
    <p>Worker</p>
    <p>Contract worker</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Add CSS to hide the dropdown initially:

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

Add CSS to position the dropdown. Have the dropdown not participate in the layout flow. and position it with a top offset of `100%` height of its parent element:

```css
.transact {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

Have the dropdown show on `.transact` hover:

```css
.transact:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

Set up on-click display, using `:target` for a CSS-only approach. When the fragment of the current URL matches the `id` of an element, the `:target` pseudo class matches said element:

```html
<a class="box transact" href="#transact">
  <div>Issue / Receive</div>
  <div class="dropdown" id="transact">
    <p>Customer</p>
    <p>Worker</p>
    <p>Contract worker</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

```css
.transact:hover .dropdown,
.dropdown:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Putting it all together:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}

:root {
  --blue: lightgrey;
  --white: black;
  --border: #edc967;
  --holder: #ccb8b8;
  --active: #b2a3a3;
}

::selection {
  background-color: var(--border);
  color: var(--white);
}

body {
  color: var(--white);
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: var(--blue);
  grid-column: 1/7;
  padding: 17px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid var(--border);
}

.header h1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

/* Dashobaord Css */

.box {
  background-color: var(--blue);
  width: 80%;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 2px dashed var(--border);
  height: 70%;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: end;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: var(--white);
}

.box:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 3px solid var(--border);
}

.box:active {
  background-color: var(--active);
}

.title {
  grid-column: 1/7;
  width: 455.75px;
}

/* Dashobaord Css End */

.transact {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.transact:hover .dropdown,
.dropdown:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ht.css">
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="header">
            <h1>Company</h1>
          </div>
          <a class="box inv" href="#">
            <div>Inventory</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box transact" href="#transact">
            <div>Issue / Receive</div>
            <div class="dropdown" id="transact">
              <p>Customer</p>
              <p>Worker</p>
              <p>Contract worker</p>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a class="box ledger" href="#">
            <div>Ledgers</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box customer" href="#">
            <div>Customers</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box treasury" href="#">
            <div>Expenses</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box treasury" href="#">
            <div>Expense Transaction</div>
          </a>
          <a class="box treasury" href="#">
            <div>Profit</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```